How do I install AWS CLI on Mac running Python 2.7?
I need to install (and utilize) AWS CLI, which requires Python 3.8 or higher. My Catalina Mac has 2.7.16.
I installed 3.12 via the link at https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html. I see when running the IDLE app that comes with it that I'm at 3.12.4 but terminal still thinks I'm running 2.7.16.
I see various warnings to not change the default version of Python running in Mac OS.
When I attempt to install AWS CLI it tells me my version of Python is unsupported and I need to use 3.8+.
I'm unsure how to proceed. Is there a way for AWS CLI to use the newly installed 3.12 rather than the default OS 2.7 version?

Make sure you are running the right command. Try python3 or python3.12.

^^This and also install AWS CLI using pip3 install awscli command

How are you attempting to install the AWS CLI?

@chepner I'm using this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/v1/userguide/install-macos.html#install-macosos-bundled - downloading via the direct link (since curl wasn't working), unzipping and running sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws. Will try the pip3 approach suggested.

Do you need the v1 cli? Or the latest v2? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html#getting-started-install-instructions

Thanks all for the helpful guidance. I'm understanding that using pip3 allows me to intentionally use python3, rather than using the "bundled installer" approach offered as the first option in AWS's guide. Now I just need to get curl working so I can install pip3 - but that's a different problem. As for v1 vs v2, I was provided the link to v1. I see if I use v1.19.x I can continue using Python 2.7. I will see if that will work.

I didn't even realize there was a v2 until I read @OneCricketeer's comment above.
The v2 install was a whole different story. Downloadable installer, which seems to have also installed the necessary version of Python. It's working fine now.
